# mariaDB insert multiple rows where 2 cols not exists

Tags: mysql, mariadb, bulkinsert

I realize similar questions have been asked before, but I can't seem to find a solution that fits this particular scenario.

I would like to insert multiple rows of data into a mariaDB table where the data must be unique (primary key excluded).

Sample table:

| enrollmentsID | classID | userID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 7 |

So if I want to insert a number of rows, I don't want to duplicate what's already present.

The general idea is something like:

```
INSERT INTO `enrollments` (`enrollmentsID`, `classID`, `userID`)  
VALUES (NULL,1,2),(NULL,1,3),(NULL,1,4),(NULL,1,5)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  
    SELECT `enrollments`.`classID`, `enrollments`.`userID` 
    FROM `enrollments`)
```

Here, userID 5 would insert but userID 3 and userID 4 would be ignored.
Unfortunately, the WHERE is causing issues...  Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: Any reason you don’t want a unique key on user and class?

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes, a user could be in multiple classes.

Comment: A unique key on 2 columns enforces unique combinations of both columns.  It would not prevent a user being in 2 different classes -- only duplicate rows for a user in the same class.

Comment: @gview, I did not know this!  Thank you to both!  When I tried to "ALTER TABLE `enrollments` ADD UNIQUE(`classID`)" I got error "Duplicate entry '2' for key 'classID_2'"

Comment: @gview, so then I truncated the table and changed classID and userID cols to 'unique' and now I can't add more than 1 user to a class: "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'classID_2':

Answer (score 1):

As P.Salmon mentioned in the comments, a UNIQUE index on the two columns is likely what you need. The index needs to be on both columns, not a `UNIQUE` index for each column.

```
ALTER TABLE enrollments
ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`classID`,`userID`)
```

From there you can do `INSERT INGORE INTO` instead of `INSERT INTO` and that will only insert the unique entries.

Comment: Thanks so much to all.  I was using phpMyAdmin to add unique indexes on each column separately and did not realize this would cause the issue above.  Thanks again!